# How read the data in class

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

I'm new to OOP in PHP.
I have created a class `Users` with (id, pseudo, email, password) and a class UsersManager which communicates with my database.

I'm working on creating a login so i have created a function in UsersManager which checkes if the username and password are correct. After lerforming the check I want to create an instance of class Users with the info of the user. 
But I'm not sure how to access this.

Here is some of my code:
`UsersManage`

```
public function connect_is_true($identifiant, $password){

    $q = $this->_db->prepare("  SELECT id, pseudo FROM users 
                                WHERE (pseudo = :identifiant OR email = :identifiant)
                                AND password = :password AND active = '1'
                                ");

    $q->execute([
        'identifiant'   => $identifiant,
        'password'      => sha1($password)
    ]);

    $userFound = $q->rowCount();

    if($userFound){
        $user = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $this->get($user->id);
    }
}

    public function get($id) {
    $id = (int) $id;

    $q = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT id, pseudo, email, password, active FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    $q->execute([$id]);
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return new Users($data);
}
```

I'm trying to return a new `Users` instance with the users data, but I cant access `Users`
Login.php ->

```
    if(not_empty(['identifiant', 'password'])) {

    extract($_POST);

    $user = new UsersManager($db);
    $user->connect_is_true($identifiant, $password);
    // Here I want to have the new User created by the function get().



}
```

With a var_dump on $user I have : "object(UsersManager)#2 (1) { ["_db":"UsersManager":private]=> object(PDO)#1 (0) { } }"

Sorry for my english.. And sorry if you don't understand what I try to explain XD

Comment: `$userObject = $user->connect_is_true($identifiant, $password);`

Comment: Thank you man ! :D